# Is it possible to remove a flag?

Tags: support, flagging, flags

Is it possible to remove a flag?  e.g. if I flag a question as "Unclear what you're asking", and the OP edits the question, is it possible to remove my flag from that question?  Or if I flag accidentally or put the wrong flag or whatever, is there a way to unflag it?